# Cordova network and whitelist (intel xdk)

Tags: cordova, networking, intel-xdk, whitelist

I am using intel xdk and want to check my internet connection.

It works fine when my whitelist is empty.
But, when i'm using a whitelist (needed because i'm using an external script) it always gives "network connection 'unknown'".

How can I solve this?
(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at this link - https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/550979 Could be a possible settings issue.

Comment: I tried that already.. But i'm not using intel xdk connection... The whitelist works fine too.. But, when i use a whitelist (and only then) the networkdetection fails...  In the emulator it works fine, but on a real device it give 'unknown'. As soon i do'nt use the whitelist anymore the detections works fine.

Comment: but you have mentioned that you did use Intel xdk?

Comment: yes, that's a bit confusing maby. I use intel-xdk to compile, but i use cordova plugins for detection of network state

Comment: why don't you try vanilla Cordova for compilation??

Comment: The Emulate tab does not "emulate" real devices. The results you are seeing there have no bearing on whether or not your code is correct. Try using the Debug tab, or follow the instructions here for the most accurate debug environment > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/intel-xdk-debug-and-test-overview#RemoteChromeDevTools <